# How to play music file after fetching list of songs from Music Library?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

In my application i have to make music library. So for that i have to fetch songs from Music Library. I done till this bye following.

```
Test_MusicLibraryAppDelegate *appDeleg = (Test_MusicLibraryAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    //NSMutableDictionary *musicList = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; 

    MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
    [query addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate
                               predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(MPMediaTypeMusic)]
                               forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType]];

    for (MPMediaItem* item in [query items]) { 
        [appDeleg.arryMusic addObject:item];
    }

    NSLog(@"Count :: %d ",[appDeleg.arryMusic count]);
    [query release];
```

than display it in table view.

when i have to play song on selected index i fetch song name but don`t know how to play that song,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Test_MusicLibraryAppDelegate *appDeleg = (Test_MusicLibraryAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

//      MPMediaItem *song = [appDeleg.arryMusic objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *aURL = [appDeleg.arryMusic objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    [[self avPlayer] replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:
     [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:aURL]];
    [avPlayer play];
}
```

but my sound file not going to play...

Hey any one know about this than help me..

Thanks
AJPatel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not storing a URL in your array, you are storing instances of `MPMediaItem`

What you need to do is extract the assets url from the media item. You can do this as follows ...

```
MPMediaItem *item = [appDeleg.arryMusic objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
[[self avPlayer] replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url]];
[self.avPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize a player object(appdelegate will be a good position)

```
        MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer; //in .h file
  self.musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
 [self.musicPlayer setRepeatMode:MPMusicRepeatModeNone];
 [self.musicPlayer setShuffleMode:MPMusicShuffleModeOff];
 [self.musicPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
```

Then have to maintain an array for holding media elements

MPMediaItemCollection  *userMediaItemCollection;// in .h file
@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMediaItemCollection *userMediaItemCollection; //in .h file

You have to add your media item to the array(input list) and add that to the mediacollection list

```
[self setUserMediaItemCollection: [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems: (NSArray *) inputList]];
```

Add your media collection list to the player

```
[APP_DELEGATE.musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection: self.userMediaItemCollection];
```

Now play

```
[APP_DELEGATE.musicPlayer play];
```

Comment: The question clearly demonstrates that the user is using `AVPlayer` so to suggest he changes to use `MPMusicPlayerController` is a little misleading and isn't really answering his question.

Comment: Why have you down-voted my answer even though its been accepted? Do you consider this acceptable behaviour? It would be perfectly reasonable for me to down-vote your answer as it doesn't really help answer the question but I have chosen not to. Down-voting because I left a comment is rather immature.